# how to add dynamic content for ADF datafactory

Tags: scala, azure, apache-spark, azure-cloud-services, azure-data-factory

I want to add dynamic parameter for my ADF pipeline. I have 2 parameter and i want to concat with '/'. 
 `1. My source folder-> pipeline().parameters.sourcefolder`
 `2. My source file-> pipeline().parameters.sourcefile`

I have tried this dynamic parameter. but i am getting error.
`@concat{(pipeline().parameters.sourcefolder,'/',(pipeline().parameters.sourcefile)}`

but is giving me error. Can you please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already have the two parameter , I suggest you define the variable and use the "Set variable" activity and concatenate the parameters there .I have the Fname & Lname as the defined parameter and the below expression should work fine .

```
@concat(pipeline().parameters.Fname,'/',pipeline().parameters.Lname)
```